# AddHandler for Apache mod_asis not working

Tags: php, apache, caching, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I am developing under a vagrant box using Ubuntu 14.04LTS with the most recent recent version of the Apache2 (2.4.7) available for this server. Mod_asis has been enabled.

If I use the following configuration (copy/paste from official Apache documentation), all the .asis file content gets echoed in the browser, including the header part of the .asis file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.server.com.dev
      AddHandler send-as-is asis
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cachedcontent%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asis -f
      RewriteRule .* /cachedcontent%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asis [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Instead, if I use the following configuration, the 'cache' content is echoed properly in the browser.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.server.com.dev
      <FilesMatch \.asis>
          SetHandler send-as-is
      </FilesMatch>
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asis -f
      RewriteRule .* /cache%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asis [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Before I update my dev environment, 'AddHandler send-as-is asis' was working properly. I am wondering if there might be an issue with mod_asis, apache 2.4.7 and the use of VirtualHost.